# Recodificar variables de caracter en Rstudio

Tags: r

Soy nueva en la comunidad y muy principiante en RStudio. Estoy haciendo un trabajo y necesito su ayuda. Tengo una variable de caracter que tiene valores demasiado largos. Al momento de graficar eso estorba bastante. Me podrán ayudar para recodificarla? En el SPSS es muy sencillo, pero acá me traba todo.

La base se llama renaGBA2020 y la variable acceso_electricidad

```
unique(renaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad)
```

Los valores que tira son:

```
[1] "Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios."
[2] "Conexion irregular a la red publica"                                               
[3] "Conexion formal con medidor prepago"                                               
[4] "Conexion a la red publica con medidor comunitario"                                 
[5] "Acceso formal con consumo limitado"                                                
[6] "Conexion a la red publica con medidor compartido"                                  
[7] "No tiene conexion electrica"
```

Quisiera hacer dos cosas:

1. Acortar todos los nombres
2. La n° 3,5 y 6 quisiera reagruparlas en una sola (tienen muy pocos casos).

Intenté mutate y recode, pero no funciona. Veo que se modifican los datos, pero no impacta en la base.

Me ayudan?? Gracias !!

Comment: Muestranos tu codigo, como lo has intentado, el que y donde te trabas. Gracias

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por contestar. Intenté dos cosas:
recode_factor(renaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad, 'Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.' = 'Formal con medidor') 
Este primer código no tira error y muestra resultados, pero no impacta en la base.

Comment: Luego:
recode (renaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad, "c (Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.) = 'Formal con medidor' ")
Error in recode(renaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad, "c (Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.) = 'Formal con medidor' ") : 
in recode term: c (Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.) = 'Formal con medidor'
  message: Error in parse(text = strsplit(term, "=")[[1]][1]) : 
  <text>:1:13: unexpected symbol
1: c (Conexion formal
                ^

Comment: Tb: renaGBA2020 %>% 
mutate(Serv_luz=case_when(acceso_electricidad == "Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios." ~ 1, acceso_electricidad == "Conexion irregular a la red publica" ~ 2, acceso_electricidad == "Conexion formal con medidor prepago" ~ 1, acceso_electricidad == "Conexion a la red publica con medidor comunitario" ~ 1, acceso_electricidad == "Acceso formal con consumo limitado" ~ 1, acceso_electricidad == "Conexion a la red publica con medidor compartido" ~ 1, acceso_electricidad == "No tiene conexion electrica" ~ 5)
Funciona pero No impacta

Answer (score 2):

Los dos temas pueden resolverse fácilmente manipulando los nombres de cada categoría

```
valores <- factor(levels=c(
"Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.",
"Conexion irregular a la red publica",
"Conexion formal con medidor prepago",
"Conexion a la red publica con medidor comunitario",
"Acceso formal con consumo limitado",
"Conexion a la red publica con medidor compartido",
"No tiene conexion electrica"))

RenaGBA2020 <- data.frame(acceso_electricidad = valores)
levels(RenaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad)

[1] "Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios."
[2] "Conexion irregular a la red publica"                                               
[3] "Conexion formal con medidor prepago"                                               
[4] "Conexion a la red publica con medidor comunitario"                                 
[5] "Acceso formal con consumo limitado"                                                
[6] "Conexion a la red publica con medidor compartido"                                  
[7] "No tiene conexion electrica"
```

Con `levels()` obtenemos cada categoría, pero la función a su vez nos posibilita modificar los nombres de cada una:

```
levels(RenaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad) <- c("A", "B", "X", "D", "X", "X", "G")
levels(RenaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad)

[1] "A" "B" "X" "D" "G""
```

Simplemente tienes que indicar un nuevo vector con los valores nuevos de cada categoría, si alguno no cambia, repites el original. Si quieres unificar categorías simplemente repites el nombre, en nuestro ejemplo, las categorías 3, 5, y 6 se han unificado en la categoría que llamamos `X`.

En cuanto a lo que has intentado, creo que vas bien con `recode_factor()` el problema es que no estás reemplazando la variable original, por eso no observas los cambios:

```
RenaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad <- recode_factor(RenaGBA2020$acceso_electricidad,
              'Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.' = 'Formal con medidor') 

[1] "Formal con medidor"                               
[2] "Conexion irregular a la red publica"              
[3] "Conexion formal con medidor prepago"              
[4] "Conexion a la red publica con medidor comunitario"
[5] "Acceso formal con consumo limitado"               
[6] "Conexion a la red publica con medidor compartido" 
[7] "No tiene conexion electrica"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Patricio por tu respuesta. Todos los días aprendo algo nuevo con esto y realmente me ha sido muy útil. Gracias !!

Answer (score 1):

Es muy interesante la pregunta, porque la recodificación de variables categóricas es muy común y en R no hay una forma canónica de hacerlo. Van dos formas de resolver este problema, adicionales a la respuesta que ya tienes:

## Usando un join

Cuando es una recodificación compleja y sé que voy a tener que repetirla muchas veces en el script lo que suelo hacer es crear un data.frame con las recodificaciones en un par de columnas y las aplico con un join. Va ejemplo con código, aplicado a tu caso:

```
RenaGBA2020 %>% 
  mutate(acceso_reco = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)) -> recodificacion

recodificacion

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  acceso_electricidad                                                                acceso_reco
  <chr>                                                                                    <dbl>
1 Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.           1
2 Conexion irregular a la red publica                                                          2
3 Conexion formal con medidor prepago                                                          1
4 Conexion a la red publica con medidor comunitario                                            1
5 Acceso formal con consumo limitado                                                           1
6 Conexion a la red publica con medidor compartido                                             1
7 No tiene conexion electrica                                                                  5
```

Con este data.frame puedo hacer la recodificación cuando lo necesite. Como es un join no importa cuantas filas tenga la base de datos: cada vez que haya match en `acceso_electricidad` va a poner la categoría correspondiente en `acceso_reco`.

```
RenaGBA2020 %>% 
  left_join(recodificacion)
```

En este caso como los nombres de columnas coinciden en `RenaGBA2020` y `recodificacion` no es necesario indicar explícitamente las columnas en el join. Si los nombres no coincidieran se podrían especificar con el argumento `by =`.

Quizás para un problema de recodificación simple no valga la pena, pero si tienes muchísimas a las que aplicarles la misma recodificación tiene más sentido. Por lo general suelo guardar este data.frame con las recodificaciones como un `.csv` y entonces tengo el código (bien simple) en el script y las relaciones para recodificación (más complicadas) en otro archivo. Incluso se puede editar ese .csv en una planilla de cálculos, si te resulta más fácil.

## Con `fct_lump`

En tu caso mencionas que quieres compactar varias categorías en una porque tienen muy baja frecuencia. En ese caso la función `fct_lump` de la librería `forcats` hace exactamente eso: compactar categorías de baja frecuencia. Con `help(fct_lump)` puedes ver las variantes que tiene, que se adaptan a diferentes casos.

Simulo unos datos en las que algunas categorías tiene frecuencia 1 y las demás más que 1. Lo que busco es compactar en una sola categoría a las que tienen una frecuencia menor que 2:

```
rena

# A tibble: 20 x 1
   acceso_electricidad                                                               
   <fct>                                                                             
 1 Conexion irregular a la red publica                                               
 2 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
 3 Conexion formal con medidor prepago                                               
 4 Conexion formal a la red publica de energia electrica con medidores domiciliarios.
 5 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
 6 Conexion irregular a la red publica                                               
 7 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
 8 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
 9 Conexion irregular a la red publica                                               
10 Acceso formal con consumo limitado                                                
11 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
12 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
13 Conexion a la red publica con medidor compartido                                  
14 Conexion irregular a la red publica                                               
15 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
16 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
17 Conexion irregular a la red publica                                               
18 Conexion a la red publica con medidor comunitario                                 
19 No tiene conexion electrica                                                       
20 No tiene conexion electrica

rena %>% 
  mutate(fct_lump_min(acceso_electricidad, 
                      min = 2,    #Si tiene menos que 2 pasa a residual
                      other_level = "Nombre de la cat residual"))
```

No sirve para todos los casos, pero cuando funciona te permite resolver el problema con poquito código.

Comment: También te agradezco muchísimo la respuesta! Estudié ciencias sociales y no tengo mucha idea de los nuevos softwares estadísticos. Me ha servido y lo explicaste muy bien :)